# Loop for ARIMA in R

Tags: r, analytics, time-series

I am applying the ARIMA model to forecast the time series in R. Here is the code

```
Higher.R2.18. <- auto.arima(Diiferent_set[,7],test="adf")            
Higher.R2.18.          
plot(forecast(Higher.R2.18.,h=22))         
forecast(Higher.R2.18.,h=22)         
correlation6 <- cor(fitted(Higher.R2.18.),Diiferent_set[,7])         
correlation6
```

Now I want to apply the loop function to compute ARIMA model for 100 time series. How can I do that. Please suggest me.

Comment: How did you store your 100 time series ? in a list, matrix, or separate object....

Comment: It's in a data frame. Where each column is a time series.

Answer (score 4):

Your example can't be replicated, but this is a pretty simple problem in general. The first step is to write a function doing whatever you want to each timeseries. I'm trusting that you want to do everything in your example above, so a function like this should do the trick:

```
runArima <- function(ts){
  Higher.R2.18. <- auto.arima(ts,test="adf")            
  p <- plot(forecast(Higher.R2.18.,h=22))         
  pred <- forecast(Higher.R2.18.,h=22)         
  correlation6 <- cor(fitted(Higher.R2.18.),ts)         
  return(list(arima=Higher.R2.18.,plot=p,forecast=pred,cor=correlation6))
}
```

Then you just need to apply that function to your list of time series. The more "R" way to do it is with an apply statement:

```
arima.list <- lapply(<list of timeseries>,runArima)
```

But you can use a loop if you prefer:

```
arima.list <- vector(length(<list of timeseries>),"list")
i <- 1
for(ts in <list of timeseries>){
  arima.list[[i]] <- runArima(ts)
  i <- i + 1
}
```

Here is an example with some trivial data:

```
> library(forecast)
> #make trivial list of time series since i don't have one
> ts.list <- lapply(1:5,function(x) WWWusage)
> #run your function across list of time series
> arima.list <- lapply(ts.list,runArima)
> #look at some results
> arima.list[[1]]$arima
Series: ts 
ARIMA(2,2,0)                    

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2
      0.2579  -0.4407
s.e.  0.0915   0.0906

sigma^2 estimated as 10.13:  log likelihood=-252.73
AIC=511.46   AICc=511.72   BIC=519.22
> arima.list[[1]]$cor
[1] 0.9972077
```

Comment: if I want to do all the above tasks you did, like stationery test, build ARIMA models,  predicting, every 30 rows of the time series, how can I go about it? I have multiple time series data and a single time series has 30 years of data, I want to replicate the 30 years time series in to 4, i.e 4*30= 120 observation. Thank you very much for your assistance!